# React: jsx watch changes compilation directory for react.js

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to precompile my React JSX files with:

```
jsx --watch dev/js/ public/js/
```

I have the non-minified `react.js` file (0.9.0) in the subdirectory `dev/js/lib`. When it compiles, the React source becomes `public/AutoFocusMixin.js`. Along with being renamed, the source is "moved" to the parent directory.

This only happens when I use the **non-minified** version of React. The compiled file is not minified. I'm using the non-minified source for debugging.

I had a similar problem with version 0.8.0 -- but instead of being named `AutoFocusMixin`, the resulting file was named `$.js` and was also in the parent directory.

My solution was to manually copy the non-minified source to the correct location.

Has anyone come up with a better solution for this or see what I'm doing wrong?

--

I assume this is the offending code in the React source (below). I see what it does but am unclear of its purpose. I confirmed the file I'm using is the React core **without** add-ons.

```js
var AutoFocusMixin = {
  componentDidMount: function() {
    if (this.props.autoFocus) {
      this.getDOMNode().focus();
    }
  }
};

module.exports = AutoFocusMixin;
```

Comment: Regarding the reason for the autoFocus mixin: it's there because > IE9 doesn't support the attribute, so it polyfilled it for you. It's used by React's form elements.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a support question for this library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a bug in React. I just filed https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1145 and we'll try to get that fixed soon. As a temporary workaround you should be able to fix it by removing all lines of `react.js` containing `@providesModule`.